# Ansible, with_item problems for looping

Tags: ansible

i have a problem with the utilisation of item (with_items)
I'm looking to not use a specific value in my item.blabla[X] but i fund nothing of this kind of use in the internet.

Playbook:

```
with_items:
    - "{{ ssh_users }}"
  when: "item.cluster[0] in group_names"
```

ssh_users example:

```
- firstname: "toto"
separator: "."
separator_git: " "
lastname: "toto"
editor: "/usr/bin/emacs"
state: "present"
user: "toto"
cluster:
          - stag
          - utils
```

Inventory:

```
[cluster_media]
preprod ansible_connection=local ansible_hostname=localhost
preprodbis ansible_connection=local ansible_hostname=localhost

[cluster_box]
myboxpp ansible_connection=local ansible_hostname=localhost

[cluster_utils]
mypreprod54 ansible_connection=local ansible_hostname=localhost

[stag:children]
cluster_media

[utils:children]
cluster_utils
```

I want to change in my playbook the 0 in item.cluster[0] to allow the task to go in the item.cluster[2] and in all the possible cluster.
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

i use `with_subelements:` and its working perfectly